# how to show main method exception message on mvc view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my project I have use main method implementation for saving values from excel sheet to database. Now, I have to show main method exception message on view page where I have designed an interface to upload excel sheet and a button. Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

You could perform your error handling by overriding Application_Error in global.asax.cs. That way you can be sure that your code will only execute when an error occurs.  In here you could put a redirect to a ErrorPage.cshtml page

Here's the function:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```